# Robust command for tikz yshift

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, robust-commands

I created a robust command declared in preamble to include a small figure in the text.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\mytikzcell{\tikz  \tikzset{b2block/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=1,
        draw, rectangle split horizontal=false,inner ysep=0pt, yshift=-1cm, line width=0.05em, text width=4em, align=center, rectangle split part fill={blue!30}}} \vspace{4em} \node[b2block] {
    \nodepart{one} {\mystrutcopy \tiny  $\langle 1, [\tikz\draw[magenta,fill=magenta] circle (.5ex); \tikz\draw[olive,fill=olive] circle (.5ex);], \bot \rangle$ \enskip {$3$}}};}
```

This works as I expect and I can use it in my text by calling  \mytikzcell.

[image]

However, the cell is not aligned with the text. There is some space at the bottom of the figure and I want to make sure that the figure bottom is in line with the bottom the the text. How can I do that? I tried to use yshift and \vspace but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome! Are you looking for the `baseline` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code is nesting `tikzpicture`s, which should be strictly avoided. `yshift` has no effect in your setting, and you may be looking for `baseline`. Also you should post a complete code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, like this here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\newsavebox{\bullone}
\newsavebox{\bulltwo}
\sbox\bullone{\tikz{\draw[magenta,fill=magenta] circle (.5ex);}}
\sbox\bulltwo{\tikz{\draw[olive,fill=olive] circle (.5ex);}}
\tikzset{b2block/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=1,
        draw, rectangle split horizontal=false,inner ysep=0pt,  line width=0.05em, text width=5em, align=center, rectangle split part fill={blue!30}}} 
\DeclareRobustCommand\mytikzcell{\tikz[baseline=(tmp.base)]  
{ \node[b2block] (tmp) {
    \nodepart{one} {\strut \tiny  $\langle 1, [\usebox\bullone \usebox\bulltwo
    ], \bot
    \rangle$ \enskip 
    {$3$}}};}}
\begin{document}
(as shown here and there \mytikzcell )
\end{document}
```

[image]

My crystal ball got stolen, so I have no clue what `\mystrutcopy` is.

You can play with the `baseline` also to adjust the, well, base lines of the circles, and to align the box with the bottom of the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\newsavebox{\bullone}
\newsavebox{\bulltwo}
\sbox\bullone{\tikz[baseline=-1pt]{\draw[magenta,fill=magenta] circle (.5ex);}}
\sbox\bulltwo{\tikz[baseline=-1pt]{\draw[olive,fill=olive] circle (.5ex);}}
\tikzset{b2block/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=1,
        draw, rectangle split horizontal=false,inner ysep=0pt,  line width=0.05em, text width=5em, align=center, rectangle split part fill={blue!30}}} 
\DeclareRobustCommand\mytikzcell{\tikz[baseline=(tmp.south)]  
{ \node[b2block] (tmp) {
    \nodepart{one} {\strut \tiny  $\langle 1, [\usebox\bullone \usebox\bulltwo
    ], \bot
    \rangle$ \enskip 
    {$3$}}};}}
\begin{document}
(as shown here and there \mytikzcell )
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is extremely close to what I want! Is there way that the bottom of the box is aligned with bottom of the other words? I'll be careful to post a minimal complete example from now on :-)

Comment: @karmanaut Yes, use `baseline=(tmp.south)` instead of `baseline=(tmp.base)`.

Comment: OMG! This is terrific! I can get the alignment! Thank you!